# What happens to a WPF window after it is closed?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, window

in my WPF application I sometimes need to create a small helper window and I create the instance of the window the first time I need it.

```
if (mesareaderThreadQueWin == null)
{
    mesareaderThreadQueWin = new MesaReaderThreadQueWindow();    
}

mesareaderThreadQueWin.Show();
```

This works perfect so far. But if I close the window and invoke to code again the program crashes telling me I can't do *show* after the window already did close.

I wonder a little bit what exactly is happening here. The window is not *null* otherwise the code would just create a new instance but since I already have shown the window it seems like i can't do so again. So the window must be in some kind of in-between-state. Unable to become visible but not *null*.

Can I detect this state? Its there a way to reuse this window again other then not closing the window at all and using *hide* instead?

Comment: You can use the Hide() member instead, it will save the instance for your next use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I detect this state?

As far as I know, there is no way to access this state

> Its there a way to reuse this window again other then not closing the window at all and using hide instead?

Yes, handle the `Closing` event in the dialog window, or override the `OnClosing` method:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could handle the [`Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) event, cancel it, then hide the window:

```
window.Closing += delegate(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    window.Hide();
};
```

This ensures the `Window` never closes and allows you to call `Show()` any number of times.

It's probably superfluous given the above, but you could detect when your `Window` is closed by attaching to the `Closed` event and setting a flag there. That is, maintain your own `isClosed` variable.